# TypeError: _evaluate() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given in fastapi

Tags: python, class, fastapi

so I'm new to fastAPI and I was trying to import fastAPI but there are errors related to its library and I don't know what's wrong. I made sure I've installed the last version but still does not work. The code is only one line importing. The problem seems to be with fastAPI built-in functions.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
```

error :

```
TypeError: _evaluate() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: General advice: try finding some documentation for this fastapi; and look for any (complete, minimal) code examples of how it's supposed to work. See if you can get any of those working.

Comment: @Kaz I only imported and this happened. there is nothing to search in documentation. There shouldn't be any problem with importing, since my code only contains a single line of import and nothing else.

Comment: So you've not seen a piece of documentation which recommends `from fastapi import FastAPI`?

Comment: @Kaz I have seen a youtube video in which it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you verify what you have imported, the version of fastapi and python. You obviously have something wrong with your environment. So first create a new clean venv and install fastapi in it then create the following main file.

main.py

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(
    title="My API",
    description="My description",
    version="My version",
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")
```